# Implementing the SHA-1 hash algorithm

Tags: code-golf, hashing

The goal of this code-golf is to create a program that takes a string as input, and you have to output the [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash value as a hexadecimal number. You can find the pseudocode for SHA-1 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-1_pseudocode)

Other rules:

1. No network access
2. You're not allowed to run external programs
3. You're not allowed to use built-in methods to hash the input
4. The shortest code wins
5. It's only necessary to handle ASCII input
6. Output can be either lowercase or uppercase
7. The input can be provided using:

   1. Prompting for input
   2. Using command-line arguments
   3. Using STDIN

Test cases:

```
Input: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Output: 2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12
----------------------------------------------------------
Input: The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog
Output: 1c3aff41d97ada6a25ae62f9522e4abd358d741f
------------------------------------------------------------
Input: This is a code golf challenge
Output: f52ff9edd95d98e707bd16a7dead459cb8db8693
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>374</strike> 322 characters

```
[128]+.,.~55+64%1,*\(8*2
32?:?.*+256{base}:B~1>++"!Vi9y BRQ+@phoKD5Vj=]30z0"{96@32-*+}*?B\64/{4/{256B}%{0'=820'{64-
2$=^}/2*.?/+?%+}64*1$'&4$?(^3$&|1518500249{++[]@+@+@?*4/.?/+?%+2$+\@32*.?/++@(@+?%@-1%+}:Y~
^2$^1859775393Y
&4$3$&|3$3$&|2400959708Y
^2$^3395469782Y'n/{'~3$3$'\+20*~}/+]zip{~+?%}%}/{?+16B{.9>7*+48+}%1>}%''+
```

This is based on an exact implementation of the pseudo-code in GolfScript plus some minor encodings to shorten the code (try it [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJUaGUgcXVpY2sgYnJvd24gZm94IGp1bXBzIG92ZXIgdGhlIGxhenkgZG9nIgoKWzEyOF0rLiwufjU1KzY0JTEsKlwoOCoyCjMyPzo%2FLiorMjU2e2Jhc2V9OkJ%2BMT4rKyIhVmk5eSBCUlErQHBob0tENVZqPV0zMHowIns5NkAzMi0qK30qP0JcNjQvezQvezI1NkJ9JXswJz04MjAnezY0LQoyJD1efS8yKi4%2FLys%2FJSt9NjQqMSQnJjQkPyheMyQmfDE1MTg1MDAyNDl7KytbXUArQCtAPyo0Ly4%2FLys%2FJSsyJCtcQDMyKi4%2FLysrQChAKz8lQC0xJSt9Oll%2BCl4yJF4xODU5Nzc1MzkzWQomNCQzJCZ8MyQzJCZ8MjQwMDk1OTcwOFkKXjIkXjMzOTU0Njk3ODJZJ24veyd%2BMyQzJCdcKzIwKn59Lytdemlwe34rPyV9JX0vez8rMTZCey45PjcqKzQ4K30lMT59JScnKwo%3D&run=true)). Input will be read from STDIN.

Comment: This is the longest GolfScript I've ever seen :P

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3 - 645 chars

```
h=0x67452301,0xEFCDAB89,0x98BADCFE,0x10325476,0xC3D2E1F0
L=lambda v,s:(v<<s|v>>B-s)%2**B
B=32
R=range
m=input().encode()
l=len(m)
m+=b'\x80'+bytes((55-l)%64)+m.fromhex(hex(2**64+l*8)[3:])
for C in [m[i:i+64]for i in R(0,len(m),64)]:
 w=[sum(C[i+j]<<8*(3-j)for j in R(4))for i in R(0,64,4)];a,b,c,d,e=h
 for i in R(16,80):w+=[L(w[i-3]^w[i-8]^w[i-14]^w[i-16],1)]
 for i in R(80):f=[b&c|~b&d,b^c^d,b&c|b&d|c&d,b^c^d][i//20];k=[0x5A827999,0x6ED9EBA1,0x8F1BBCDC,0xCA62C1D6][i//20];t=L(a,5)+f+e+k+w[i];e=d;d=c;c=L(b,30);b=a;a=t%2**32
 g=a,b,c,d,e;h=[(h[i]+g[i])%2**32for i in R(5)]
B=160
print('%x'%(L(h[0],128)|L(h[1],96)|L(h[2],64)|L(h[3],32)|h[4]))
```

Just a golfed version of the pseudocode.

Comment: does utf = u8 in python3?

Comment: @YOU Yes, that works too. I just checked and it turns out that `.encode()` uses UTF-8 by default, which is even shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## D (759 chars)

Online executable version: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/f0c8508f

```
import std.range,std.algorithm,std.bitmanip,std.stdio:g=writef;
void main(char[][]x){
    auto m=cast(ubyte[])x[1];
    uint a=0x67452301,b=0xEFCDAB89,i,t,f,k;
    uint[5]h=[a,b,~a,~b,0xC3D2E1F0],s;
    uint[80]w;
    auto r=(uint u,uint b)=>u<<b|u>>32-b;
    auto u=(uint i)=>[r(s[0],5)+f+s[4]+k+w[i],s[0],r(s[1],30),s[2],s[3]];
    ubyte[64]p;
    p[0]=128;
    m~=p[0..64-(m.length+8)%64]~nativeToBigEndian(8*m.length);
    foreach(ch;m.chunks(64)){
        16.iota.map!(i=>w[i]=ch[i*4..$][0..4].bigEndianToNative!uint).array;
        iota(16,80).map!(i=>w[i]=r(w[i-3]^w[i-8]^w[i-14]^w[i-16],1)).array;
        s=h;
        80.iota.map!(i=>(i<20?f=s[3]^s[1]&(s[2]^s[3]),k=0x5A827999:i<40?f=s[1]^s[2]^s[3],k=0x6ED9EBA1:i<60?f=s[1]&s[2]|s[3]&(s[1]|s[2]),k=0x8F1BBCDC:(f=s[1]^s[2]^s[3],k=0xCA62C1D6),s[]=u(i)[])).array;
        h[]+=s[];
    }
    g("%(%08x%)",h);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### C, 546 characters

The program calculates the SHA-1 of the contents of its standard input.

```
unsigned b[16],k[]={1732584193,0xEFCDAB89,0,271733878,0xC3D2E1F0},i,j,n,p,t,u,v,w,x;
char*d=b;a(c){for(d[p++^3]=c,c=0,t=*k,u=k[1],v=k[2],w=k[3],x=k[4];
c>79?*k+=t,k[1]+=u,k[2]+=v,k[3]+=w,k[4]+=x,p=0:p>63;x=w,w=v,v=u<<30|u/4,u=t,t=i)
i=b[c-3&15]^b[c+8&15]^b[c+2&15]^b[j=c&15],c++>15?b[j]=i*2|i>>31:0,i=u^v^w,
i=(t<<5|t>>27)+x+b[j]+(c<21?(w^u&(v^w))+1518500249:c<41?i+1859775393:
c<61?(u&v|w&(u|v))-1894007588:i-899497514);}
main(){for(k[2]=~*k;i=~getchar();++n)a(~i);for(a(128);p-56;a(0));
for(;p<20?printf("%02x",(d=k)[p^3]&255):p>55;a(n*8L>>504-p*8));}
```

A couple of notes:

1. This program assumes that `int` is exactly 32 bits. For platforms where this is not the case, the `unsigned` declaration at the very beginning should be replaced by the platform's unsigned 32-bit type. (`uint32_t` would be the obvious choice, if it didn't require `#include <stdint.h>`.)
2. This program assumes a little-endian platform. For a big-endian platform, simply remove the two occurrences of `^3` in the program, and replace the initialization of `k[]` with the following block: `{19088743,0x89ABCDEF,0,1985229328,0xF0E1D2C3}`, for a size of 541 characters.
3. For implementations where `char` is unsigned by default, one can delete the `&255` that appears on the final line to save four more characters.

Comment: This returns `be417768b5c3c5c1d9bcb2e7c119196dd76b5570` for `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` but it has to return `2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12`

Comment: @ProgramFOX That hash value is for the string plus a terminating new line. The test SHA-1 values quoted in the description are for strings without terminating newlines, so don't append a newline to the input if you want to test those strings.

Comment: Suggest `'gE#\1'` instead of `1732584193`

Comment: @ceilingcat That's a good improvement. Though note that C compilers are not obliged to accept multibyte char constants, so it's not always portable. I know earlier versions of gcc, at leat, would treat them as a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

My python code is a  little longer but it is fully working.

```
data="hello world"
bytes = ""
h0,h1,h2,h3,h4=0x67452301,0xEFCDAB89,0x98BADCFE,0x10325476,0xC3D2E1F0
for n in range(len(data)):bytes+='{0:08b}'.format(ord(data[n]))
bits=bytes+"1"
pBits=bits
while len(pBits)%512!=448:pBits+="0"
pBits+='{0:064b}'.format(len(bits)-1)
def chunks(l,n):return[l[i:i+n]for i in range(0,len(l),n)]
def rol(n,b):return((n<<b)|(n>>(32-b)))&0xffffffff 
for c in chunks(pBits,4512):
    words=chunks(c,32)
    w=[0]*80
    for n in range(0,16):w[n]=int(words[n],2)
    for i in range(16,80):w[i]=rol((w[i-3]^w[i-8]^w[i-14]^w[i-16]),1)
    a,b,c,d,e=h0,h1,h2,h3,h4
    for i in range(0,80):
        if 0<=i<=19:f=(b&c)|((~b)&d);k=0x5A827999
        elif 20<=i<=39:f=b^c^d;k=0x6ED9EBA1
        elif 40<=i<=59:f=(b&c)|(b&d)|(c&d);k=0x8F1BBCDC
        elif 60<=i<=79:f=b^c^d;k=0xCA62C1D6
        temp=rol(a,5)+f+e+k+w[i]&0xffffffff
        e,d,c,b,a=d,c,rol(b,30),a,temp 
    h0+=a
    h1+=b
    h2+=c
    h3+=d
    h4+=e 
print '%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x'%(h0,h1,h2,h3,h4)
```

Comment: Please specify the language in the answer. Also, since this is code-golf, you should at least attempt minification. One-char variable names, removing unneccesary whitespace, stashing expensive constants (`0xffffffff`) into variables (also, would `-1` suffice?)...

Comment: looks like phython to me :)

Comment: @JanDvorak I modified my code.

Comment: `h0..h4` are still two-letter ;-)

Comment: I get a syntax error at line 29.